# How to check some checkboxes using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

The page has many checkboxes, how to check only productB checkboxes using JS?

```
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="5174234"></td>
<td>ProdA</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="2171123"></td>
<td>ProdB</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="1174228"></td>
<td>ProdB</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="6178232"></td>
<td>ProdB</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="6171239"></td>
<td>ProdC</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="9178630"></td>
<td>ProdC</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="8894221"></td>
<td>ProdB</td>
<td><input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="5478234"></td>
<td>ProdB</td>
...
```

Comment: Please use a unique selector(`class` or `data-attribute`). Relying on text for search is a bad idea. Also `id` **should be unique**. Also you have wrapped  text in `td` but inputs are hanging any how. My suggestion, *please fix your markup first*. This will ease DOM access and manipulation by a ton

Comment: Something like this: `const check = (title, on) => document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]').forEach(check => {if(check.parentNode.nextSibling.text === title) check.checked = on;})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use td as you done, or you'll not be able to get the text inside it with js, thats a similar solution.

```js
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    names=document.getElementsByTagName('label'),
    textNames=[];
for(var i in names){
  textNames.push(names[i].innerHTML);
}
for(var i in inputs){
  var name=textNames[i];
  if(name==='ProdB'){
    inputs[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="5174234">
<label>ProdA</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="2171123">
<label>ProdB</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="1174228">
<label>ProdB</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="6178232">
<label>ProdB</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="6171239">
<label>ProdC</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="9178630">
<label>ProdC</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="8894221">
<label>ProdB</label>
<input type=checkbox id="active" name="checkbox" value="5478234">
<label>ProdB</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues inside of it.

**First** off your  tags should be wrapped inside the td-tags, not outside of it.

```
<td> 
    ProdA
    <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="checkbox" value="5174234">
</td>
<td>
    ProdB
    <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="checkbox" value="2171123">
</td>

...
```

Is a better structure.

**Second**, you have duplicate id's, which isn't allowed either. Make them unique.

```
<td> 
    ProdA
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-a" name="checkbox" value="5174234">
</td>
<td>
    ProdB
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-b" name="checkbox" value="2171123">
</td>

...
```

**Third**, now with the unique ids you can easily find the element inside javascript using the id. You can use [getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) for this so for example:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-b").checked = true;
```

Comment: @channasmcs That's why in the second code block, I explained him how he should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use unique id for each checkboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
           document.getElementById("active2").checked = "checked";
           document.getElementById("active3").checked = "checked";
           document.getElementById("active4").checked = "checked";
           document.getElementById("active7").checked = "checked";
           document.getElementById("active8").checked = "checked";
    });

</script>

<input type=checkbox id="active1" name="checkbox" value="5174234" />
ProdA<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active2" name="checkbox" value="2171123" />
ProdB<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active3" name="checkbox" value="1174228" />
ProdB<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active4" name="checkbox" value="6178232" />
ProdB<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active5" name="checkbox" value="6171239" />
ProdC<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active6" name="checkbox" value="9178630" />
ProdC<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active7" name="checkbox" value="8894221" />
ProdB<br />
<input type=checkbox id="active8" name="checkbox" value="5478234" />
ProdB<br />
```